# I'm trying to select the checkbox type of input and then appending table column

Tags: jquery

I have multiple inputs type checkbox - and if any one of them is checked, I want to append a column (JUST ONE TIME) - i.e. if any of the other checkbox types are marked after the first one is, I do not want to add the column again, which it does keep doing.  I did get it adding just once PER each checkbox type input.  However, I also want to just add a column once across the WHOLE document (i.e. across all checkboxes on the page).

Here's relevant parts of code

```
<table id="edhist_table" >
<tr id="table_headings">
    <th>Graduated?</th>     
</tr>

    <tr>            
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="college_grad" value="yes">yes</input></td>

</tr>   
<tr id='grad_part'>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grad_grad1" value="yes">yes</input></td>   

</table>


<script>
//if any of the checkboxes are checked  - shoudl append column  
$( "[type=checkbox]").one("click",function() {
    $( "#table_headings" ).append("<th id='degree_heading'>Degree/Certificate Name</th>");
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.one` will execute at most one per element which means it will fire for each element one time (this is causing you duplicates.  You need to check if the element has been added and if not add it.    You can change it to this:

```
$( "[type=checkbox]").one("click",function() {
   if ( $( "#table_headings #degree_heading" ).length==0)
      $( "#table_headings" ).append("<th id='degree_heading'>Degree/Certificate Name</th>");
});
```

Comment: oh my gosh - THANK YOU.  It makes complete sense

Comment: There are actually other ways to check, like you don't need the `length==0` part however I find the more explicit way is easier to understand.   Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just close your function:

```
$( "[type=checkbox]").one("click",function() {
    $( "#table_headings" ).append("<th id='degree_heading'>Degree/Certificate Name</th>");
}); // <-- Here
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pYx6b/